# Assert Failed Expected:<Null> Actual:<(null)>

Tags: c#, unit-testing, null, assert

So I'm unit testing and I got the above message. I've looked around and cannot find an answer to my problem. I have no idea what this means. Can there be two different kinds of Null? Thanks for the help!

```
//This is invalid input given to the CategoryList constructor. It returns a null value.    
//The message i get is: Assert.AreEqual failed. Expected:<Null>.Actual:<(null)>.

CategoryList test = new CategoryList(
    Primitives.ConstantPrimitives.ConnectionString, 
    Primitives.ConstantPrimitives.negativeShort, 
    false);
Assert.AreEqual(test.Cat_ID, null);
```

Here is CategoryList

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Data.SqlTypes;

namespace Retail_Utilities.Util.DataClasses
{
    public class CategoryList
    {
        public SqlInt16 Cat_ID { get; set; }
        public String Cat { get; set; }
        public Boolean Active_YN { get; set; }
        public SqlDateTime Last_Update { get; set; }
        public Int16 Parent_Cat_ID { get; set; }
        public Int16? Top_Level_Cat_ID { get; set; }
        public Int16? Pallet_Type_ID { get; set; }
        public CategoryList ParentCat { get; set; }

        public bool IsChild { get; set; }

        public CategoryList()
        {
            IsChild = false;
        }

        public CategoryList(string connectionString, Int16 catID, Boolean isChild = false)
        {
            IsChild = false;

            using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
            {
                SqlCommand command = connection.CreateCommand();
                string sqlCommand = "SELECT TOP 1 Cat_ID, Cat, Active_YN, Last_Update, Parent_Cat_ID, Top_Level_Cat_ID, Pallet_Type_ID, Deactivated_On";
                sqlCommand += " FROM Twr_List_Cat WHERE 0=0";
                sqlCommand += " AND Cat_ID = " + catID;
                command.CommandText = sqlCommand;
                connection.Open();
                SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
                if (reader.HasRows)
                {
                    while (reader.Read())
                    {
                        IsChild = isChild;
                        Cat_ID = reader.GetSqlInt16(0);
                        Cat = reader.GetString(1);
                        Active_YN = reader.GetBoolean(2);
                        Last_Update = reader.GetSqlDateTime(3);
                        Parent_Cat_ID = reader.GetInt16(4);
                        Top_Level_Cat_ID = reader.IsDBNull(5) ? null : (Int16?)reader.GetInt16(5);
                        Pallet_Type_ID = reader.IsDBNull(6) ? null : (Int16?)reader.GetInt16(6);
                        if (!IsChild) { ParentCat = new CategoryList(connectionString, Parent_Cat_ID, true); }
                    }
                }
                reader.Close();
            }
        }

        public static List<CategoryList> ListActiveCategories(string connectionString)
        {
            List<CategoryList> activeCats = new List<CategoryList>();
            using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
            {
                using (SqlCommand command = connection.CreateCommand())
                {
                    command.CommandText = "SELECT Cat_ID, Cat, Active_YN, Last_Update, Parent_Cat_ID, Top_Level_Cat_ID, Pallet_Type_ID";
                    command.CommandText += " FROM Twr_List_Cat";
                    command.CommandText += " WHERE Active_YN = 1;";
                    connection.Open();
                    SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
                    if (reader.HasRows)
                    {
                        while (reader.Read())
                        {
                            CategoryList activeCat = new CategoryList
                            {
                                Cat_ID = reader.GetSqlInt16(0),
                                Cat = reader.GetString(1),
                                Active_YN = reader.GetBoolean(2),
                                Last_Update = reader.GetSqlDateTime(3),
                                Parent_Cat_ID = reader.GetInt16(4),
                                Top_Level_Cat_ID = reader.IsDBNull(5) ? null : (Int16?)reader.GetInt16(5),
                                Pallet_Type_ID = reader.IsDBNull(6) ? null : (Int16?)reader.GetInt16(6),
                            };
                            activeCat.ParentCat = new CategoryList(connectionString, activeCat.Parent_Cat_ID, true);
                            activeCats.Add(activeCat);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            return activeCats;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Debug the unit test and inspect the value of `test.Cat_ID`.

Comment: it is a short indeed. i changed it to a (short?) null and it still gave the same message as before.

Comment: Sounds like it doesn't return `null`, but rather an actual `CategoryList` that simply is defined as not representing any actual data (a common enough pattern) but as we don't know anything about that type, we can't say for sure.

Comment: @Servy I tried that. Then i get the message Expected:<Util.DataClasses.CategoryList>.Actual:<Util.DataClasses.CategoryList>. Which makes even less sense :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there are several types of "null" in .Net:

- regular `null`
- `DBNull` and related "nothing there yet" for DataBases like one you have - [SqlInt16](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqltypes.sqlint16%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)
- Nullable types with no value
- Additionally any type defining its `ToString` to print something like `null` whenever it wants and possibly defining comparisons/`.Equals` to `null` to return `true`.

It looks like you have `SqlInt16` with no value at hand based on `<(null)>` output.

Possibly you are looking for  `IsNull` property of that type instead:

```
Assert.IsTrue(test.Cat_ID.IsNull);
```

Comment: I changed it to be Assert.AreEqual(test.Cat_ID, DBNull.Value.Equals(null));

but now the message says:
Expected:<Null(System.Data.SqlTypes.SqlInt16)>.Actual:<False(System.Boolean)>.

why would the error message change for test.Cat_ID?

Sorry!

Comment: @Shikumaru - `SqlInt16.IsNull` is probably what you need (added to answer too) .

Comment: I tried Assert.AreEqual(test.Cat_ID, SqlInt16.Null.IsNull); I get the message Expected:<Null(Systen.Data.SqlTypes.SqlInt16)>.Actual:<True(System.Boolean)>.  
I was unable to do SqlInt16.IsNull.
The second answer of just asserting cat ID.IsNull also failed :(

Comment: @Shikumaru just debug your unit test and see what value actually is.

Comment: the value is Null. I have it writing out what it is. Thats why this all doesnt make sense :( Im sorry!

Comment: that works. @GrantWinney ! SqlInt16.Null
Thanks so much...This has been terrible, and I apologize for how long its taken!